# In OSX, when packaging a Qt5 app bundle using CMake/CPack, the app icon doesn't show

Tags: macos, cmake, qt5, cpack

I'm trying to build a Qt5 app using CMake on OSX.  I can build and run the app just fine. I have a proper .icns file that OSX shows as working just fine.  However, the app icon doesn't show.

```
#Bundle (OSX)
CONFIGURE_FILE("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}.plist.in" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Info.plist")
SET(CPACK_BUNDLE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}")
SET(CPACK_BUNDLE_STARTUP_COMMAND ${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME})
SET(CPACK_BUNDLE_PLIST "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Info.plist")
SET(CPACK_BUNDLE_ICON "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/graphics/favicon.icns")
```

All I see is this (wrong icon)

[image]